# How to use xterm.js with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, xtermjs

I'm trying to user [xterm.js](https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js) in my Meteor app and I can't make it works because I got `Terminal is not defined`.

I use xterm like this in my client's main.html:

```
<script src="../imports/ui/xterm.js"></script>
        <div id="terminal"></div>
             <script>
               var term = new Terminal();
               term.open(document.getElementById('#terminal'));
               term.write('Hello from \033[1;3;31mxterm.js\033[0m $ ')
             </script>
```

And xterm is imported because if I take a look in the terminal I can see: 
[image]

Someone has already used xterm.js with Meteor and could put me on the right track ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work this way. You need to import the file in your `client/main.js` file and use its function after:

client/main.js:

```
import '../imports/ui/xterm.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  var term = new Terminal();
  term.open(document.getElementById('#terminal'));
  term.write('Hello from \033[1;3;31mxterm.js\033[0m $ ')
});
```

Remember to remove the two script tag in `main.html` file.

**Update**: if it still does not work, then let move the `xterm.js` file to `client/compatibility/xterm.js` and remove the `import` statement in the code above.

Comment: When I do that I can't see xterm.js in the dev console and I still got the same error

Comment: The `xterm.js` file, how did you get it? Could you make sure that it works on browser? maybe let try add it to a static html file to see if it works

Comment: If I do localhost/js/xterm.js, the file is displayed on my browser. (Yes I moved xterm.js but I did it too with your answer).

And I got it by doing a copy of the repo and moving dist/xterm.js in my project

Comment: Now I have `TypeError: Terminal is not a constructor`

Comment: Ok now it "works", I have no error and something is displayed but it's very ugly and I'm sure it's not how it should be but I'll try to find why it's displayed like this

Comment: Did you include the css file comes along with js file?

Comment: Yes I did but should I place it in /client/compatibility ?

Comment: I think it should be in `client/lib/css` folder

Comment: are you able to type into the console once it shows up in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question here with meteor! But it's an add for those who landed here working on an Electron app or a workflow that doesn't support the ES6 import statement. Node at version 8 and early 9 don't support yet ES6 import statement! if you are in such a situation! Here how you should do to import it:

```
//importing xterm (because node don't support import {Terminal} from 'xterm';)
const xterm = require('xterm');
var Terminal = xterm.Terminal;
```

it go in two steps! you require first xterm. then you get a reference to Terminal class.

Hope it help!